# A better way to get the value of an NFC card?

Tags: python

I've written a small python script to get the value of an NFC card, but I keep running into small annoying problems and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. Right now my code looks like this:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-AH02MAUE', 9600)

def rfidResponse(responseID):
    rID = responseID.strip();
    print repr(responseID)
    print rID
    if rID == "750047FB76BF":
        print "This one"
    else:
        print "other one"

while True:
    try:
        response = ser.readline()
        stringResponse = str(response)
        rfidResponse(stringResponse)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

ser.close()
```

I'm trying to compare a read card to a particular sting (in this case `750047FB76BF`). The problem is that when I look at `rID` I get `750047FB76BF`, when I do `print repr(responseID)` I get `'\x02750047FB76BF\r\n'`. What's even more frustrating is that output only happens on the first swipe of the card, each following swipe outputs `'\x03\x02750047FB76BF\r\n'` so even doing some sort of slice won't work every time.

Is there a better way to do this? Or ideally to be able to actually use rID as my comparison value (letting me avoid the slice etc).

Comment: Why not use a regular expression to do the matching?

Comment: `responseID` is the output of reading from `serial` .. I think it's better to try to extract NFC card ID through `regex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently when you read from the `serial` you get `NON-ASCII` characters, so I think you might want to try with `re` module instead to parse what you read from the serial port and retrieve your `NFC ID` but I will assume here that when you read from the serial port you will get `NFC ID` at the end of your line, just before EOL(`\r\n`), so It's better if you just print whatever you receive from the serial port to be sure that's the 'NFC ID`is the last thing you get and if it's more than that, then we have to change the`re` expression.

Here we go:

```
import serial
import re

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbserial-AH02MAUE', 9600)

def rfidResponse(responseID):
    #rID = responseID.strip() #no need for stripping, instead do the next line:
    #print responseID #you can print without `repr`.
    print responseID
    if responseID == "750047FB76BF":
        print "This one"
    else:
        print "other one"

while True:
    try:
        responseID = ser.readline()
        #stringResponse = str(response) # you don't need this line
        response = re.search('[A-Z0-9]{12}(?=\s+)', responsID) #your NFC ID should be of fixed length
        if response:
            rfidResponse(response.group(0))
        else:
            print 'No NFC ID received'
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ser.close() #better also close `serial` communication in case of exception
        break

ser.close()
```

Comment: I tried out your code but I get the error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rfidTest.py", line 19, in <module>
    response = re.search('[A-Z0-9]{12}(?=\s+)', responsID) #your NFC ID should be of fixed length
NameError: name 'responsID' is not defined`

Comment: Ok so there were a few small edits I needed to do to get it working - I'll mark yours as answered if you can fix them:

change `response = ser.readline()` to `responsID = ser.readline()`

also change `rID` to `responseID`

Comment: @Mike...edited...sorry I was busy with my job...hope this helped you

Comment: No worries - it worked perfectly one I made the tweaks

Comment: There are a few errors in this that submitted can you review and accept them